# Authentication to display my Wall on my website

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get a JSON object of my Facebook wall posts to display on my website but it seems to be ridiculously complicated for such a simple task.

Do I need to implement server-side redirects and then post data back 'pretending' to be a user just so that I can get a token or am I misunderstanding something here?!

How can I request the JSON object of my Wall Stream given the fact that I have an API key & secret etc? Currently I can't work out how to turn these details into a proper access_token that can actually be used with `FacebookClient.Get("Me", parameters)`.

I've read somewhere that I can get an `infinite session key` that will never expire but following the steps given [here](http://blog.jylin.com/2009/10/01/loading-wall-posts-using-facebookstream_get/) simply cause an error at the 2nd step.

I have read loads of documentation and tried to find examples but almost everything I've found starts after authentication.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to get an access token (there is no getting around this). This is done via an OAuth Dialog where the user signs-in and provides the required permission. You will have to request the "offline_access" and "read_stream" permissions to do what you are trying to. Getting the access_token is pretty simple. Follow the instruction here: http://osnapz.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-asp-net-with-facebooks-graph-api-and-oauth-2-0-authentication/

Also, read up Facebook's documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

You will have to store your access token somewhere for later use (this is the infinite session key)

After you get the access token, you can call the graph API directly:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed/?access_token=YOUR-TOKEN-HERE
```

OR you can use the Facebook C# SDK (recommended).

FYI, the link you posted is out-dated and Facebook will not support that method soon.

**UPDATE - MANUAL WAY OF GETTING AN ACCESS TOKEN:**

Since you are only interested in your data, so you will only have to get the access token ONCE. Of course, you will have to do this again if you change your password.

I will detail a manual way of getting your token.

1. Make sure you are using Firefox. It actually displays JSON strings.
2. Navigate to this URL. Add your App ID, callback-url (this should match the domain you in your registration). I have added a lot of permissions.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=popup&client_id=YOUR-APP-ID&redirect_uri=YOUR-CALLBACK-URL&scope=offline_access,read_stream,email,read_insights,user_events,user_groups,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_notes,user_photo_video_tags,user_photos,user_relationships,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,read_friendlists,read_requests,friends_likes,friends_location,friends_notes,friends_photo_video_tags,friends_photos,friends_relationships,friends_religion_politics,friends_status,friends_videos,friends_website,friends_work_history,user_checkins,friends_checkins

1. Once you authenticate and "Allow", Facebook will redirect to your callback URL is a "code" parameter. Make a note of this parameter.
2. Now call another URL, add your app id, api secret, and the code.

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR-APP-ID&redirect_uri=YOUR-CALLBACK-URL&client_secret=API-SECRET&code=CODE-YOUR-COPIED-BEFORE

1. Calling the URL above will display the access token in the browser. Save this access token. Now you can use this token to make API calls on your behalf.
2. Remember, you will have go through this process again if you change your password.

This is a manual way and only intended in your scenario where you are only interested in your data. I do this for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice dotnetster I'll give it a go.

I don't understand why a developer has to go through the login procedure when it's their data (i.e. relates to their API Key etc). I don't want people to post comments or access their data, all I want is to request my wall data as JSON in VB.Net.

Wouldn't it be better to be able to just use an ID/API Key/Secret combination in my ASP.Net, thus validating myself, then just get the JSON (this is the way all the other API's I currently use work)? 

It seem so unnecessarily complicated that I'm questioning whether I've completely misunderstood!

Comment: The API is meant for a developer to develop applications that serve their user community. Hence, the security features. The API key/secret is for your application, not your user account. You still have to go through the same procedure of authentication before you can access your information.

Comment: Thanks dotnetster both solutions worked perfectly. The 'very manual' one seems to have given me a permanent access token which I can now use with no problems. I've used the code from the other link to form the basis of a logon class which I'll use if (when) the specifications of the current project change to allow people to post replies etc. Thanks, once again.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for being the one and only person ON THE ENTIRE INTERNETS to provide relatively straightforward, step-by-step instructions on getting an accessToken! One thing you might want to add to your steps is how to get an APP KEY and SECRET CODE: by logging into your facebook account and going to this URL: http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php